# Is there an efficient solution to the travelling salesman problem with binary edge weights?

Tags: traveling-salesman

Is there a way to solve TSP in polynomial time if there are only two kinds of weights, 0 and 1?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, since if every edge has weight 1, there is still the question of whether any such tour exists, which is the [Hamiltonian Cycle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_path) problem, and this is still NP-hard.  (The link is to a Wikipedia page for Hamiltonian Path -- both the path and cycle versions of the problem are hard.)

Comment: I initially read the question with the assumption it's asking about complete graphs - but then you can still get the Hamiltonian Cycle problem by asking if a zero-length Hamiltonian cycle exists. And if you allow retrace, the problem becomes trivial.

Comment: @JohnDvorak thanks a lot, is there a way if I guarantee no Hamiltonian Cycles?

Comment: Every complete graph has a Hamiltonian cycle. And if your graph doesn't have a Hamiltonian cycle ... then it definitely doesn't have a Hamiltonian cycle, so what was the question again?

Comment: @WiccanKarnak : (A TSP solution is a Hamiltonian cycle ... of minimal total weight.)

Comment: Aren't you allowed to use the same edge twice in TSP?

Comment: @immibis: That (and the question of whether the underlying graph is complete or not) would depend on how the question is formulated, and I don't know if there is a definitively canonical definition of TSP.  FWIW, the definition on p. 211 of Garey & Johnson (1979) specifies the output as a *permutation* of the vertices, implying the(ir) answer is "no".  (They also require distances to be in $\mathbb Z^+$ for each pair of cities, which actually rules out 0-length edges, making the 0-1 TSP problem described here technically *not* a special case of TSP...)

Answer (score 3):

The [accepted answer](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/105985/9550) isn't quite right. An instance of TSP consists of a distance between every pair of cities: that is, it consists of a weighted complete graph. Every complete graph has a Hamiltonian cycle.

However, it is simple to reduce HAMILTON-CYCLE to $0$–$1$ TSP. Given a graph $G$, create a TSP instance where the cities are the vertices and the distance is $0$ if there is an edge between the cities and $1$ if there is not. Then $G$ has a Hamiltonian cyle if, and only if, the TSP instance has a tour of weight zero.  Therefore, $0$–$1$ TSP is **NP**-complete.

Comment: This is a good point, though the choice of whether to require the input graph to be complete or not never makes a practical difference (for the purpose of finding a distance-minimal tour, missing edges in a graph can be encoded as arbitrarily-distant edges in a complete graph).  Interestingly, in looking for a definitively canonical definition of the TSP problem, I found that on p. 211 of Garey & Johnson (1979) they require the edge weights to be in $\mathbb Z^+$ -- i.e., 0-length edges are forbidden, meaning that for them, the "0-1 TSP" described here is technically not a special case of TSP!

Comment: @j_random_hacker It's a good job I'm only throwing small stones in my glass house! (Actually, you can reduce $0$-$1$ TSP to $1$-$2$ TSP by just adding one to every edge weight and adding $n$ to the length of the path you're looking for.)